# Error with relationship MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Receiving this error when trying to create a controller. Happens right after I choose create.

[image]

Comment: Please post the relevant code and error message, not an image of it.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the `ForeignKey` attribute as follows:

```
public virtual Ingredient Ingredients { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Ingredients")]
public int IngredientId { get; set; }
```

Basically, you must specify the name of the property in the ForeignKey attribute.

---

Anyway, you can also write the opposite:

```
public int IngredientId { get; set; }    
[ForeignKey("IngredientId")]
public virtual Ingredient Ingredients { get; set; }
```

See more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958.aspx)

Comment: Technically this is correct, but the only issue was the that OP had `ForeignKey("Ingredient")` (singular), rather than `ForeignKey("Ingredients")` (plural). The order of the properties is of no consequence. However, @MR, it would be better to change the name of your property to singular, since it's only a single `Ingredient`.